# How to automate the re-run activity for a failed pipelines in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have the pipelines configured for 2 activities in the ADF

1. Copy data activity
2. Stored Procedure activity

These pipelines are triggered for every hour. Here the problem is we have to make the pipelines auto re-run if any of the activity got failed. Scenario screenshot

[image]

Expectation: I have an option to retry the pipeline for the activity level. But it is not the best solution to enable because of the trigger interval.

Scenario: If pipeline started and ran for 30 min, 1st activity failed after 30 min. If we enable this setting, then it again runs for 30 min wrt the stored procedure activity. Mean while as per the scheduled trigger the same pipeline will run again.

This causes the target lock and duplicate executions of same pipelines.

I need a best solution to automate the ADF pipeline activity failures for the automatic re-run's. Retry option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you don't want your ADF pipeline to run more than once simultaneously.
This can be achieved using the "concurrency" setting in the pipeline settings tab:

[image: pipeline settings]

1 means that when a pipeline is running, and it's time for the trigger to activate another run, the new run will be in status "queue" until the first run ends.

So you can have a retry set at the activity level, and still, a new pipeline instance will wait for the first one to complete.

Please note that if this happens a lot, you may end up with multiple pipeline runs in status "queue" waiting to run (the maximum is 100).